# tkinter window opens but no widget shows up

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started working with tkinter and written the below simple code. However, after running no widget appears in the opened window.

```
import tkinter;
root = tkinter.Tk ();
root.geometry ("400x450");

main_window = tkinter.Frame (root);
main_window.pack ();

mode = tkinter.Frame (main_window);
if_tx = True;
tx_switch = tkinter.Radiobutton (mode , text = "Tx" , variable = if_tx , value = True);
tx_switch.pack (padx = 5 , pady = 5);
rx_switch = tkinter.Radiobutton (mode , text = "Rx" , variable = if_tx , value = False);
rx_switch.pack (padx = 5 , pady = 5);

root.mainloop ();
```

The only thing that appears is this:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are new to python. In python, we don't use semicolons to mark the end of sentences. Also while importing tkinter, we have to import everything from it instead of import itself. And finally, you aren't packing the mode variable.

The correct code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Radiobutton
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x450")

main_window = Frame(root)
main_window.pack()

mode = Frame(main_window)
mode.pack()
if_tx = True
tx_switch = Radiobutton(mode, text="Tx", variable=if_tx, value=True)
tx_switch.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
rx_switch = Radiobutton(mode, text="Rx", variable=if_tx, value=False)
rx_switch.pack (padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it helped you!!

Comment: Thank you @Swagrim. The packing of mode solved my problem. However, when I import everything from module tkinter, I face the following warning:

'from tkinter import *' used; unable to detect undefined names

Comment: What when you directly import tkinter?

Comment: using `*` when importing is a bad practice, you shouldn't do that and much less suggest it

Comment: @Matiiss You mean from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Radiobutton etc..?

Comment: @AR_Hasani and @Matiiss now it might be fine I guess, as per the edited answer. (`from tkinter import *` to `from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Radiobutton`). And if you want to use any other widget, you must add the widget's name at the end of this line with a comma(,) before the name.

Comment: yes that is better, one can also simply use `import tkinter` or `import tkinter as tk` and then they need to simply prefix each of the widgets with `tkinter.` or `tk.` accordingly which also help understand others where the name comes from